How do I label pictures like a formula？

I saw in the book "Large networks and graph limits" that the author labeled a picture like a formula. I am very curious about how this is done. Could you please tell me how I can achieve the same effect as in the picture? Thank you very much.
Also, is the addition and subtraction of these graphs not implemented with code? Are they drawn directly with vector graphics software? Or can they be implemented directly with code?

There's nothing all that special about including images, as they are just objects set within the equation. Here's an example:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f(x) = \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image-a} \, x^2 
         + \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image-b} \, x 
         + \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image-c}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image-a} \, x^2 
         + \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image-b} \, x 
         + \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image-c}       \\
  \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image-a} \, x^2 
    + \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image-b} \, x 
    + \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image-c}
    &= g(x)
\end{align}

\end{document}

If you know how to draw the images (graphs) using TikZ, say, then you can include that code as well. Or, draw the images externally and include the image files like I did above.

Thank you, brother. I haven't seen this before. Thank you very much for your answer

@Klein To elaborate, the purpose of the {figure} environment is two-fold: allow the figure to float to an appropriate place, and number the caption.  You need neither.  Nothing requires that a {figure} and \includegraphics go together.

This is only an idea. I will suggest to use dynkin-diagrams
Here an example,

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\dynkin E8 \,\geq 2 \, \dynkin[mark=o]E8 \, - \, \dynkin A{oto}
\end{equation}
\end{document}

or use tikz-cd package.
